# Solving $e^{iz} = 3^{1/2} -i$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question says find all $z \in {\mathbb C}$ that satisfy $e^{iz} = 3^{1/2} -i$. Write your answer(s) in standard form.

First thing I did was change the RHS to polar form ($2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{6}}$), and then with the LHS I simplified and manipulated it to $e^{-y}(\cos x + i\sin x)$ using Euler's equation. Im not too sure where to go from here. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Begin by showing that $$e^z = 1 \iff z = 2n\pi i$$ for some integer $n$. Now note that $2 = e^{\ln{2}}$, so you have

$$e^{iz} = e^{\ln{2} - i\pi/6}$$ which can be rearranged to state

$$e^{iz - \ln{2} + i\pi/6} = 1$$

Comment: But they ask for it in standard form and to plot it after. How do I get that from what you showed above?

Comment: @JonathanY. No. It's meant to just be a characterization of the $z$ for which equality holds. So the final answer would follow from setting $iz - \ln{2} + i\pi/6 = 2n\pi$.

Comment: @MathStudent If you set $iz - \ln{2} + i\pi/6 = 2n\pi$ and equate real and imaginary parts, you can write down exactly what $x$ and $y$ are.

Comment: and no, no imaginary unit was missing in what I posted

Comment: Oh wait sorry I was wondering how the $ln(2)$ will affect my answer. Doesn't sound like it will be a special triangle case when I go to plot my answer.

Comment: Right now I have $-(ln(2)-2\pi n)+(z+ \dfrac{\pi}{6})i=0$ ...

Answer (score 2):

$z = x + {\rm i}y$.

$$
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}x}{\rm e}^{-y} = \sqrt{3\,} - {\rm i}\,,
\quad
{\rm e}^{-y}\cos\left(x\right) = \sqrt{3\,}\,,
\quad
{\rm e}^{-y}\sin\left(x\right) = -1
$$

$$
\tan\left(x\right) = -\,{\sqrt{3\,} \over 3}\,,
\quad
{\rm e}^{-2y} = 4\,,
\quad
x = {5 \over 6}\,\pi + n\pi\,,
\quad
n \in {\mathbb Z}\,,
\quad
y = -\ln\left(2\right)
$$

$$\color{#ff0000}{\large%
z_{n}
=
\left(n + {5 \over 6}\right)\pi
-
{\rm i}\ln\left(2\right)\,,
\qquad
n \in {\mathbb Z}}
$$

Comment: I must upvote this since he got the correct answer before I did. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|e^{i(x+iy)}|=e^{-y}$ implies $y=-\ln 2$.

Comment: So that would just come from $(e^{-y})(e^{ix})=2e^{-i\dfrac{\pi}{6}}$ since $e^{-y}=2$?

Comment: Yes, if two complex numbers are equal, then their moduli are equal and their arguments may differ only by an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ :

$$e^{iz}=e^{-y+ix}=e^{-y}\cos x+ie^{-y}\sin x=\sqrt3-i\iff$$

$$e^{-y}\cos x=\sqrt3\;,\;\;e^{-y}\sin x=-1\implies\frac{\sqrt3}{\cos x}=-\frac1{\sin x}\iff$$

$$\tan x=-\frac1{\sqrt3}\iff x=\frac{5\pi}6+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

and then

$$e^{-y}\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}6+k\pi\right)=\sqrt3\implies e^{-y}=\pm2$$

and since the minus sign in the last equality is impossible, we get

$$e^{-y}=2\implies y=\log\frac12=-\log2$$

Thus

$$z=\left(\frac{5\pi}6+k\pi\right)-i\log2$$

Comment: How do you plot this?

Comment: Well, the imaginary coordinate is a constant, whereas the real one is *also* a constant for any fixed $\;k\;$ ...