# Solving $e^{iz} = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on solving the equation $e^{iz} = 1$ for all possible complex numbers $z$. I looked through the solutions on [Solving $e^{iz} = 3^{1/2} -i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514994/solving-eiz-31-2-i), but when I follow that logic I get stuck on $e^{-y}  sin(x) = 0$, which results in $y =-\infty$?

I thought about converting 1 into polar form, but that results simply in 1 again?

Comment: "*I also got stuck on another, non related, question:*"  [You should delete that part of this question and ask it as a separate one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting $z=x+iy$, the equation $e^{iz}=1$ becomes
$$
e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)=1,
$$
i.e.
$$
e^{-y}\cos x=1, e^{-y}\sin x=0.
$$
Since $e^{-y}>0$, solving the second equation $e^{-y}\sin x=0$, we get
$$
x=k\pi,\quad k\in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Now, the second equation becomes
$$
(-1)^ke^{-y}=1,
$$
and therefore $k$ has to be even, and $y=0$. Hence $z=2k\pi$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why can't $k$ be odd and $y$ compensate for that?

Comment: Because $x$ and $y$ are real, so $e^{-y} > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use Euler's formula: $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$. Note that for $1= \cos z+i\sin z$, $\sin z= 0$ AND $\cos z =1$.

Comment: I believe this is only valid for real $z$. Instead the OP should use $e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$ and *then* apply Euler's formula.

Comment: Should've thought of that. My mistake.

Comment: @JackM: I suspect Euler would have gone "pffft" to that objection. :-)

Comment: $e^{iz} = \cos z + i\sin z$ is still valid for non-real $z$ (both sides are entire and equal on the real line thus equal everywhere), but you can't immediately conclude from $$1= \cos z + i\sin z$$ that $\sin z = 0$ and $\cos z = 1$, since $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are not necessarily real.